# Generate method snippet Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, code-snippets

Problem is simple. I click <kbd>ctrl+.</kbd> and generate method looks like below:

[image]

I want to have there `private async Task` instead of `internal`. I googled code snippet refactor, change etc and I can't find it. Sb know how to change it?

Comment: u can create a custom snippet yourself.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019

Comment: Visual Studio is just a tool isn't magic, exists some things you need to write

Comment: I recommend you to use such best thing as ReSharper Templates Explorer to manage Visual Studio code snippets, if you can handle it.